# Ruby on Rails problem with rendering a layout and using link_to_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble using the link_to_remote method while rendering a layout.

For example in a controller:

```
def show
  render :layout => 'generic_logged'
end
```

In a view:

```
<%= link_to_remote 'Delete', {:confirm => "Are you sure?", :url => {:controller => :opinions, :action => :delete_opinion, :id => @opinion.id}}, :method => :delete %>
```

If I use the render :layout statement in my controller the link_to_remote method doesn't work. If I leave it out the link_to_remote method works.

Anyone know why I am experiencing this behavior, and how I can go about fixing this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

link_to_remote uses prototype or jquery helpers ( depending on which you're using ).

If you've overriden the layout you'll need to include rails default javascripts in your new layout, so add:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

to your new layout ( if you look at application.html.erb, you'll see how its done there if this is new to you )

Comment: Well, I though about your answer and realized that I forgot to include prototype.js in my layout file. Thank you for the help!